# SQL query (at least)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to write an SQL query but I couldn't translate the idea into code, and I'm seeking help here.

So, what I want to perform is:
If one of these columns have value then 1 else 0, I mean, at least if one of these 4 columns have value then count.

I hope I'm clear enough, thank you in advance :)

Comment: Please make this a complete question by including sample data along with the expected output.

Comment: `sum(case when c1 + c2 + c3 + c4 > 0 then 1 else 0 end)`

Answer (score 0):

for columns c1, c2, c3, c3 try
IF ( CONDITION, 0, 1)
where CONDITION is  (A and B and C and D)
where A is ( ISNULL  ( c1 ))
or combined

```
 IF ( (ISNULL(c1) and ISNULL(c2) and ISNULL(c3) and ISNULL(c4)) , 0, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using conditional [COUNT_IF](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/count_if.html) and [COALESCE()](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/coalesce.html):

```
SELECT COUNT_IF(COALESCE(col1, col2, col3, col4) IS NOT NULL) AS cnt
FROM tab;
```

If any column contains data then `COALESCE` will pick the first value, satisfy the `IS NOT NULL` condition and count it.